# Detect a closed connection in python's telnetlib

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm using python's [telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html) to connect to a remote telnet server. I'm having a hard time detecting if the connection is still open, or if the remote server closed it on me.

I will notice the connection is closed the next time I try to read or write to it, but would like to have a way to detect it on demand.

Is there a way to send some sort of an 'Are You There' packet without affecting the actual connection? The [telnet RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854.html) supports an "are you there" and "NOP" commands - just not sure how to get telnetlib to send them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to send a NOP this way:

```
from telnetlib import IAC, NOP

... 

telnet_object.sock.sendall(IAC + NOP)
```

Comment: What else do  you have to do to detect the connection is closed?  I grabbed the socket with "socket_ = tn.get_socket()", then sent the "NOP" but no exceptions were raised.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that for some reason sending only once was not enough ... I've "discovered it" by accident, I had something like this:

```
def check_alive(telnet_obj):
    try:
        if telnet_obj.sock: # this way I've taken care of problem if the .close() was called
           telnet_obj.sock.send(IAC+NOP) # notice the use of send instead of sendall
           return True
    except:
           logger.info("telnet send failed - dead")
           pass

# later on
logger.info("is alive %s", check_alive(my_telnet_obj))
if check_alive(my_telnet_obj):
     # do whatever
```

after a few runs I've noticed that the log message was saying "is alive True", but the code didn't entered the "if", and that the log message "telnet send failed - dead" was printed, so in my last implementation, as I was saying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42096317/4020610), I'm just calling the `.send()` method 3 times (just in case 2 were not enough).

That's my 2 cents, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Following up on David's solution, after `close()` on the interface, the `sock` attribute changes from being a `socket._socketobject` to being the integer 0. The call to `.sendall` fails with an `AttributeError` if the socket is closed, so you may as well just check its type.

Tested with Linux and Windows 7.

Comment: To emphasize, this check can only be used if the telnet connection was closed on your side.  If the connection was closed remotely then the type of the object stays as "socket._socketobject" and NOT integer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to detect if a connection is close it's by socket object. So,it's easier to check it this way,

```
def is_connected(telnet_obj):
    return telnet_obj.get_socket().fileno()
```

If it is closed return -1

I took this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861484/how-to-know-the-if-the-socket-connection-is-closed-in-python).